# Relación no existe en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

estoy trabajando con postgresql con el siguiente  codigo

```
WITH tmp_asn_id AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ucc) AS id_lote, ucc
    FROM temp_asn GROUP BY ucc
),

tmp_asn AS (
    SELECT num_pedido, numero_envio, bodega_entrega, numero_bodega, bodega_destino, total_lotes, total_piezas, ucc, codigo, talla, cantidad
    FROM temp_asn
)

INSERT INTO ctlpedidosasn SELECT DISTINCT A.numproveedor, B.num_pedido, C.id_lote, current_date FROM movpedidosp0 as A INNER JOIN temp_asn as B ON B.num_pedido = A.numpedido and B.bodega_destino = A.numbodegadestino
INNER JOIN tmp_asn_id AS C ON C.ucc = B.ucc ORDER BY id_lote;

INSERT INTO tmp_asn_lotes select b.num_pedido, b.numero_envio, b.bodega_entrega, b.numero_bodega, b.bodega_destino, a.id_lote, b.total_lotes, b.total_piezas, b.ucc, b.codigo, b.talla, b.cantidad
FROM tmp_asn_id AS a
JOIN tmp_asn AS b
ON a.ucc = b.ucc
ORDER BY a.id_lote, codigo, talla;
```

Originalmente solo estaba el segundo insert y funcionaba correctamente, pero al agregar otro insert a ctlpedidosasn me marca ese error **Relation "tmp_asn_id" does not  exist**
como si no encontrara a tmp_asn_id, pero no comprendo, cuando solo esta el segundo insert funciona correctamente y tambien consulta a tmp_asn_id, como es posible que al agregar otro insert consultando a la misma tabla no encuentre tmp_asn_id?

Comment: No entiendo como son tus tablas y el porqué hacer dos `INSERT`. Podrías colocar más información?

Comment: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ucc) AS id_lote, ucc FROM temp_asn GROUP BY ucc` no tiene sentido.